# How to gather information from user input and apply it elsewhere

Tags: python

Hi I am new to programming and I am trying to write a code that will gather information from the input and determine if it is a valid alphabet.

This is my code so far

```
words = []
word = input('Character: ')
while word:
  if word not in words:
    words.append(word)
 word = input('Character: ')
print(''.join(words),'is a a valid alphabetical string.')

suppose I choose three letters then the output of my code then pressed enter on the fourth, 
the code will be:

Character:a
Character:b
Character:c
Character:
abc is a valid alphabetical string.

I want to add to this code so that when I type in a character that is not
from the alphabet the code will do something like this.

Character:a
Character:b
Character:c
Character:4
4 is not in the alphabet.
```

This is how I want my program to work

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.isalpha()`
It is gives only true if all characters in the string are letters.

Example:

```
>>> 'test'.isalpha()
True
>>> 'test44'.isalpha()
False
>>> 'test test'.isalpha()
False
```

In your code:

```
words = []
word = input('Character: ')
while word:
 if word.isalpha() and word not in words:
   words.append(word)
 word = input('Character: ')
print(words,'is a a valid alphabetical string.')
```

Comment: It works with me, i using python 3 .. what is the exception?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `while` loop to collect input, then break out of the loop if either the input is empty (the user hit enter without inputting a character) or if the input is not in the alphabet.

```
letters = []
while True:
    letter = input('Character:')
    if letter == '':
        if letters:
            print('{} is a valid alphabetical string.'.format(''.join(letters)))
        else:
            print('The input was blank.')
        break
    elif letter.isalpha():
        letters.append(letter)
    else:
        print('{} is not in the alphabet.'.format(letter))
        break
```

Comment: One more thing if the user was to hit enter without an imput. how would I make it print The input is blank.  For example                                           Character: then printing on the next line                                                                                                            The input was blank.

Comment: How would you want to distinguish between a user hitting enter and displaying "___ is a valid alphanumerical string." and the user hitting enter and displaying 'The input is blank.'? Do you mean if no letters were entered previously?

Comment: I will edit my question at the top and show a diagram, easier to understand

Comment: If you look at the bottom of the diagram you will see what I mean. if the user enters nothing, the program should output a message indicating that The input was blank.

Comment: Updated answer to what I think you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out :-

```
words = []
while 1:
    word = input('Character: ')
    if word != '':
        try:
            if word.isalpha():
                pass
            if word not in words:
                words.append(word)
        except Exception:
            print word, " is not in the alphabet"
            break
    else:
        res = (''.join(words) +' is a valid alphabetical string.') if (words != []) else "The input was blank."
        print res
        break
```

Comment: This works but how would I address the second part of my problem

Comment: I want to be able to do countless characters plus this code doesn't work

Comment: go to my second problem at the top. That is something how I want it, however you can go to countless letters

Comment: It is working perfectly for me. Pasting the output for your reference. For countless character, just replace your code by count. Did the same for you.

Comment: What second problem are you referring to ?

Comment: I do not want it to print df is a valid alphabetical string if an incorrect symbol was placed for example the number 4. I only want it to say 4 is not in alphabet. And when writing the inputs I dowt want to write them as strings like 'd' I want to write just the letter d.

Comment: Plus I want to be able to do countless characters not just 3

Comment: Please refer to the actual question and diagrams above

Comment: If you check the question again I have added an image. Which makes it more clear on the output I want

Comment: Now this should work with all your conditions...  1. Enter Countless character 2. Blank input parsing 3. Printing output on encountering blank input 4. Shows Numbers as invalid input.....   Adding to that , here while entering number as input, you don't need to pass as string like '4', rather you can just pass as simple integer 4. The exception part will take care of it....